# Getting parent classess from innerText element

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm not extremely familiar with puppeteer and node.js but need to do this ...

Need to click on button which has span element. Button and span doesn't have ids, classes are changed with every page load. Only what is certain is text "Login" inside span element.

Button type is submit and I can find it thru that but submit doesn't run all js on that button like with click.

```
<button class="But_case_8U1 Log_but_dCL">
    <span class="ButChild_3Jw">Login</span>
</button>`
```

I tried watch some tutorials and examples but all puppeteer and node.js examples are simpler than my problem.

Comment: Please share more context, your code so far and preferably the actual page as a [mcve]. Two elements doesn't offer enough information for determining the best way to select an element or reproducing an element not being clickable. Often, there's a solid id or class a few layers up that offers plenty of disambiguation. Clicking`button[type="submit"]` should do the job, so if it doesn't, we'd need to see the actual page. Sometimes events are on different elements than you think.

Comment: I'm not looking for the best solution. 
There is not any id on any button or on any span inside button. Classes are created in random way. Random part is at the and of class name.
Only part which is constant is text inside button > span element. They can change text but they have limited number of options.
I need puppeteer node.js way to find button using text inside button span element and click on that button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use The `Login` text if you have only one element button with text `Login` in you page like this:

```
const [button] = await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'Login')]");
if (button) {
    await button.click();
}
```

Comment: Actually, my question was bad, I was not good with node.js.
This resolve all of my problems
    const html = await page.content()
    button_class = Array.from(html.split(">Login</span>")[0].split("<button")).pop().split(' class="')[1].split('">')[0].split(" ")[2]